# Load coordinates from database to Google Maps

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, mysql

How can I load coordinates (lng/lat) from a database (MySQL) into a map service like Google Maps or Leaflet?

Currently I only have a JavaScript which loads a GeoJSON file with coordinates.

I want to inject them from my database to the map. I'm not very skilled in web development.

Why can't I just do SQL queries in JavaScript and print the results to the map like in Java where I just loop the result set and operate on my data.

Or do I have to use PHP or some other server side scripting language? The issue is, I have to use Java to process the coordinates.

Comment: you can use php to retrieve your lat/lngs with most databases (mysql,postgres) https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 uses javascipt (not java)

Comment: I have to use Java at least somewhere. A user http their coordinates and thats when I neeed java to process them. Could I use java store them in a DB and then use PHP to retreive the data from the DB to show on the map?

Answer (score 2):

You could use software like MapServer or GeoServer to read your database and provide the data as a layer of layers as part of a WMS and/or WFS.

So you use Java to populate the database, and a WMS/WFS service to provide access to the data.  You don't need to use any server-side scripting to get the data.